# Yosemite Toolbar Style

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift, osx-yosemite

How do I get the new toolbar item style of OSX Yosemite?

I created a standard toolbar, but the buttons don't have that button-like look. Do I need to drag actual buttons to the toolbar to get this look?

What I have:

[image: have]

What I want (that round bezel and white background):

[image: want]

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to do. I'm assuming you are working in a storyboard, and have dragged a "toolbar" object into a view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of items in toolbars, image items and view items. It looks like you have an image item. You seem to want a view item where the view is an `NSButton` configured as a round textured button. So, yes, you should drag actual buttons to the toolbar.

I would not attempt to control the button background. You should use the button as-is to get the default system appearance. Apple recommends using a PDF template image (all black with the alpha channel used to make the image). The button itself would not have a title/label. Rather that would be on the containing toolbar item.

It looks like you may have applied an internal blue "glow" or highlight to your image. Generally, you should not do that. Let the frameworks apply appropriate effects to the template image automatically based on the button state and shows-state-by mode.

[Toolbars in the Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/WindowTitleBarToolbar.html)
[Controls which are appropriate to use in the window frame (including the toolbar)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ControlsAll.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH46-SW2)
[Designing images for toolbar buttons](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ToolbarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH89-SW3)

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine for my Cocoa app under Yosemite -
are you actually setting the [template property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/setTemplate:) for your icon images..?

From the `NSImage` docs:

> The 'template' property is metadata that allows clients to be smarter
>   about image processing.  An image should be marked as a template if it
>   is basic glpyh-like black and white art that is intended to be
>   processed into derived images for use on screen.

Comment: Pages also has colored icons (with gradients etc) so they couldn't have used templates